# Borel $\sigma$-algebra with $\sigma$-finite measure: does a function vanish almost everywhere outside its essential support?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, borel-measures, second-countable

Let $(X, \mathcal B(X), \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space with $\mathcal B(X)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a topological space $X$. The [essential support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support) of $f:X \to \mathbb R$ is defined as
$$
\operatorname{ess-supp} (f) := \bigcap \{F \text{ closed} \mid f= 0 \, \mu\text{-a.e. on } F^c\}.
$$

In this way, $\operatorname{ess-supp} (f)$ is always closed.

Can below theorem be generalized to spaces which are **not** second-countable?

> **Theorem:** If $X$ is second-countable, then $f = 0$ $\mu$-a.e. on $(\operatorname{ess-supp} (f))^c$.

---

**Proof:** Let $S := \operatorname{ess-supp} (f)$. Then
$$
S^c := \bigcup \{U \text{ open} \mid f= 0 \, \mu\text{-a.e. on } U \}.
$$

Let $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ be a countable base of the topology of $X$. Let $J$ be the collection of those $j \in I$ such that $f=0$ $\mu$-a.e. on $O_i$. Then
$$
S^c = \bigcup_{i \in J} O_i.
$$

For each $i \in J$, there is a $\mu$-null set $N_i \in \mathcal B(X)$ such that $N_i \subset O_i$ and $f=0$ on $O_i \setminus N_i$. Let $N := \bigcup_{i \in J} N_i$. Then $N \in \mathcal B(X)$ is a $\mu$-null set such that $f = 0$ on $S^c \setminus N$. This completes the proof.

Comment: It is well known that the result fails in general topological spaces. A. Totrat has many results on supports of measures ion general topological spaces.

Comment: To convert from ess support of a functon $f$ to consideration of support of a measure, use the measure $\tau(E) = \int_E |f|\;d\mu$.  It will be sigma-finite.

Comment: @geetha290krm I could not find the reference related to A. Totrat. Could you please provide me with a link?